# Is there any flaw in this proof relating derivative and monotonicity?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I came across this lemma in my notes:

Suppose that $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f'(c)$ exists for some $c \in (a,b)$. 
If $f'(c) > 0$, then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that 
$$f(x) < f(c), \quad \forall x \in (c-\delta,c) \, \cap \, (a,b), \\
f(x) > f(c), \quad \forall x \in (c,c+\delta) \, \cap \, (a,b) .
$$
Proof is as follows.

Since $f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} > 0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that
$$0 < |x-c| < \delta \implies \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} > 0$$
If $x \in (c-\delta, c)\, \cap \, (a,b)$, then $x-c< 0$ and 
$$f(x)-f(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\cdot(x-c)<0$$

Therefore, we get $f(x) < f(c)$.

By a similar argument, if $x \in (c, c+\delta)\, \cap \, (a,b)$, then $f(x) > f(c)$.

We define $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, where
$$g(x):= \begin{cases}
 x+x^2\sin(\frac1x) & \text{ if } x \neq 0 \\ 
 0 & \text{ if } x= 0
\end{cases}$$

Why doesn't this lemma hold for $g(x)$?

Comment: At what point do you think it doesn't hold? Obviously it doesn't apply at x=0 since g'(0)=0 which isn't greater than 0.

Comment: But it _does_ hold in that case, even for $x=0$. Draw the function and see. @WilliamKrinsman: $g'(0)=1$.

Comment: Even if the statement does hold in that case, that doesn't mean that the lemma is wrong. That's like saying the statement "most plants are green" is incorrect because some lizards are green and they aren't plants. Also I am fairly certain that the statement doesn't hold for g at x=0, given that the function oscillates infinitely often at that point.

Comment: I have mixed up this function with its variant without the $x$. This is my mistake. Should I delete the question at this point?

Comment: No I think I was the one who mixed up the function with its variant without x; I get the question now

Comment: My guess is that the lemma probably does hold then, since on (-1,1), we have that $x^2 = o(x)$ as $x \to 0$, so the $x$ term dominates and there probably does exist a neighborhood around 0 where g is monotone, since close enough to 0 the oscillations, which are bounded by $x^2$ in magnitude, can't dominate the behavior of x near 0.

Comment: @WilliamKrinsman $g$ oscillates infinitely, but is squeezed between $x+x^2$ and $x-x^2$, which means that for small positive $x$, $g$ is positive, and for small, negative $x$, $g$ is negative. That is exactly what the lemma says should happen.

Comment: yeah I agree, see my comment above

Comment: Note that the lemma does _not_ say that the function is monotone on any interval, only at that single point. $g$ illustrates that nicely, and even better if you swap $\sin(1/x)$ with $\sin(1/x^2)$.

Comment: I get it! Positive derivative of $f$ at a point $c$ only tells us about how values near $c$ relates to $f(c)$. To say that $f$ is increasing in an interval $I$, we require $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$, assuming $f$ is differentiable. Thank you Arthur and William!

Comment: The lemma was for functions defined on $(a,b)$ and it looks like your purposed $g(x)$ was defined on $R$. Your $g(x)$ does have the darboux property though!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I have visualized the graph differently in my head.

$g(x)$ is an example for a differentiable function that has a positive derivative at a point $x=0$ yet not monotonic for any neighborhood around $0$.

Since $g(x) < 0$ for $x < 0$ and $g(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$, this property is as stated by the lemma and does not serve as a counter-example.